# What is the proper way to ask two questions in one sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, questions

Every now and again I find myself writing a sentence like this:

> INPUT in LPINPUT is some data structure I can identify — what does LP mean, array?

I don't know what to call this type of sentence but the general format is that I ask a question and then list one or more possible answers.

Now in the quote above I used a comma to separate the original question and my supposed answer but would it not be correct to use two question marks? Like so:

> INPUT in LPINPUT is some data structure I can identify — what does LP mean?
>   array?

Because the way I see it, I'm asking two questions.

Comment: BTW: LP probably means long pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking two questions in the same sentence can be hard to understand. Try using more sentences instead.

> INPUT in LPINPUT is some data structure I can identify. What does LP mean? Does it mean array?